# What the inheritating class structure looks like?

Tags: c++

All:

When I study polymorphism in C++, I find a small example here:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base{
public:
virtual void f(float x){cout<<"Base::f(float)"<<x<<endl;}
        void g(float x){cout<<"Base::g(float)"<<x<<endl;}
        void h(float x){cout<<"Base::h(float)"<<x<<endl;}
};

class Derived:public Base{
public:
virtual void f(float x){cout<<"Derived::f(float)"<<x<<endl;}
        void g(int x){cout<<"Derived::g(int)"<<x<<endl;}
        void h(float x){cout<<"Derived::h(float)"<<x<<endl;}
};
int main(void){
  Derived d;
  Base *pb=&d;
  Derived *pd=&d;

  //Good:behavior depends solely on type of the object
  pb->f(3.14f);     //Derived::f(float)3.14
  pd->f(3.14f);     //Derived::f(float)3.14

  //Bad:behavior depends on type of the pointer
  pb->g(3.14f);     //Base::g(float)3.14
  pd->g(3.14f);     //Derived::g(int)3(surprise!)

  //Bad:behavior depends on type of the pointer
  pb->h(3.14f);     //Base::h(float)3.14(surprise!)
  pd->h(3.14f);     //Derived::h(float)3.14


  return 0;
}
```

After study virtual function, I think I got the idea how the polymorph work, but there are still some question in this code, I do not want bother someone explaining how this code work, I only need someone who can show me detail inside the Derived class( no need for too much detail, just show how the method function pointer(or index) arranged in Vtable and structure for those are not virtual inheritated one).

From pb->h(3.14f);     //Base::h(float)3.14(surprise!)
I guess there should be several vtables, am I right?

Thanks!

Comment: You are right.  The functions should be `virtual`, which would provide a vtable for each class type.

Comment: Sorry Drew, it is my poor english! This is working code, I just want to know some inside detail about how Derived Class structure?

Answer (score 2):

Your code only has one polymorphic (`virtual`) member function signature in it: `f(float)`.  The other three functions, `g(float)`, `g(int)`, and `h(float)` are not virtual.  Since your "(surprise!)" comments are after calls to `g()` and `h()`, I'm guessing that you are either surprised that these functions are not polymorphic, or you are actually surprised by the behavior of non-polymorphic functions.

If you're surprised that `g()` and `h()` aren't polymorphic, realize that `virtual` is placed before *each* polymorphic function.  If a function isn't declared `virtual`, it will only be polymorphic if it has the same signature as a virtual function in the base class (which also means that your `virtual` in `Derived` is redundant, but I personally feel that such redundant use of `virtual` is good style).  Since `virtual` only appears before `f(float)`, only `f(float)` will be polymorphic.

Since `h()` isn't polymorphic, it's not a surprise that calling `h()` through a base pointer calls the base version of `h()`.

With regard to `g()`, a name in a derived class hides any corresponding name in the base class unless brought back in via a `using` declaration.  This is why `pd->g(3.14f)` calls `Derived::g(int)` even though `Base::g(float)` is a better match.  `Base::g` isn't visible.  If you put `using Base::g;` in class Derived, it will call the float version of `g()`.  (Note that `virtual` would make no difference for `g()` here, since `g(int)` and `g(float)` are different function signatures -- there's no way one would override the other.)

HTH

Comment: Thanks Adam, I wonder if you can give me some explaining from the Physical Structure side like how can the pointer find position of according functions?

Comment: @Kuan:  The implementation of polymorphic functions isn't part of the standard, so any implementation details I could give may be wrong from compiler to compiler.  However, it is very common for an identifier (e.g. a pointer) to be placed at the beginning of instances of polymorphic classes, which is used to identify the derived type or to find a table of code/data offsets for virtual calls.  Sometimes there are more than one such tags in each instance (often with multiple inheritance).  Details of such tables vary across platforms.  It's better to learn the required behaviors instead.

Comment: Thanks Adam, but I wonder if you can give me some best tips how to remember or category those rules related to virtual inheritate / non-virtual inheritate, overloading, override, and hidden? Or which rules among those do you think is most important to remember?

Comment: @Kuan: I can't really give you a synopsis of those rules in a comment like this; there's not enough space.  Perhaps it would be best to post it as a new question (especially if it includes specifics on which behaviors you are wondering about, perhaps in a bulleted list).

Comment: @Kuan: Perhaps a short answer would be:  The static type of the pointer's class at the call site will determine which function is called from the overload set visible in that (possibly base-)class.  If that selected function is virtual (either because it's declared virtual or because it was inherited as a virtual function), the actual function called will be the most-derived override.  Otherwise, it will be the version in that pointer's static class, regardless of any derived classes the pointer could point to.